# selenium click position on firefox and chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver with java and have a input type text that have half of his body under a floating div. So the left half is reachable but not the right side.

I'm testing it with firefox and chrome. Under firefox it work perfectly, the textbox receive a click and the test continu.

But under chrome, I get this error message
Element  is not clickable at point (490, 327). Other element would receive the click: ...

Is there a way to change the position where chrome try to click by default. And if possible without having to change all my click to actions and manually change the position for each.

Thank you

Edit:

Trying to solve this, I check the position of the click on a input. With firefox, I get the position: 77.5X and 30Y. And with chrome I get 264.5X and 30Y. They both click on a different spot on the input... is there a way to change this?

Comment: Please post your code and if possible, a link to the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `move_by_offset(x,y)` method and see if chrome clicks at the specified co-ordinates. Under your chrome tests section, you can specify, which co-ordinates to actually click.

```
element = find_element_by_selector(selector)
act = ActionChains(browser)
act.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said the right side is unreachable; you can bring it into view by using the following code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

You can try clicking on it then after ensuring that it is clickable i.e. displayed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe chrome is working faster than firefox, try adding a wait with expected conditions. something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);       
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.elementToBeClickable(By.id("yourElementId"))));
```

Comment: I tried adding the wait, but didn't change anything